# How to show Weekly Slider using HighStock

Tags: highcharts

I have a scenario where i have to show chart data weekly for a particular year.
I need to change high-stock slider to display week ranges i.e from 1-52.
Can anyone please suggest how can we customize high stock slider for this scenario.

I'm totally stumped and also not sure is it possible using High Stock.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dchPe/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this using bootstarp two way slider and slicing the series data of highchart according to the week selected.